# Handshake failure socket connection with cipher TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, jdk 1.7 and tls 1.2

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, java-7, tls1.2

I want to establish SSL connection between a server and a client (using socket) with jdk 1.7 protocol TLS 1.2 and cipher suite TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256.

The client-side code:

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(Resources.getResource("trust.keystore").openStream(),
        "changeit".toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
        TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ks);
    SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslCtx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    socketFactory = sslCtx.getSocketFactory();
    Socket s = socketFactory.createSocket("localhost", 4443);
    ((SSLSocket)s).setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{
        "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
    });
    ((SSLSocket)s).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{
        "TLSv1.2"
    });
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    writer.write("HELLO WORLD\n");
    writer.flush();
```

The server-side code:

```
    ServerSocket ssocket =
        ((SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory
            .getDefault()).createServerSocket(4443);
    ssocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
    ((SSLServerSocket)ssocket).setEnabledProtocols(
        new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});
    ((SSLServerSocket)ssocket).setEnabledCipherSuites(
        new String[] {"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"});
```

I have the following exception:

```
    pool-2-thread-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
    pool-2-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000000: 01: 515  0303  0303  0000  0202  02    28                                                                .........
..(
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28          pool-2-thread-1, called closeSocket()
                                    .(
pool-2-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
server cipher suite [TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
server enabled protocol [TLSv1.2]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:266)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:894)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:622)
```

The same code is working with jdk 1.8.

Comment: Cipher suites with SHA384 and SHA256 are available only for TLS 1.2 but it is not enabled by default on Java 7. Did you enable it? https://tonyyan.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/enabled-tls-1-2-and-tls-1-1-on-java-7/

Comment: Yes, I've already enabled it by "-D=https.protocols=TLSv1.2 -D=jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2".